# SQLAlchemy inserts not reflected in remote database

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to insert a record into a mysql table on a remote database. The python works (no errors) but none of my inserts are reflected on the remote database. It seems like SQLAlchemy maintains a cache and is updating it but not pushing it. I've even dropped the table on the server and SQLAlchemy continues to believe it exists.

I'm not using `Session` or otherwise committing the transaction, although when I echo the statements, it seems like a commit is occurring.

Does SQLAlchemy maintain some sort of cache?

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy import Table
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

db_engine2 = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://user:pass@host/product_analytics', echo=True)
meta = MetaData(db_engine2)

xlations_topic_update_status = Table('product_analytics.xlations_topic_update_status', meta, autoload=True)
xlations_topic_update_status.insert().execute({'topic_name':'test','topic_id':'test2'}, autocommit=True)

print(xlations_topic_update_status.select().execute().fetchall())
```

The below is what I see even *after* I've dropped the table on the server:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out...

`Table('product_analytics.xlations_topic_update_status', meta, autoload=True)` silently created a table in the product_analytics database called "product_analytics.xlations_topic_update_status". Instead of using the "xlations_topic_update_status" table

Lesson learned: Do not include the database name.